# Почему файлы не запускаются через выделенную программу?

Tags: windows, реестр

В чём ошибка?

Мне нужно, чтобы файлы запускались через выделенную программу, а они требуют "Выбрать программу"...

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\notepad] 
@="Open with Rnote2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\notepad\Command] 
@="C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Мои документы\Rnote_\Rnote.exe %1"
```

Answer (score 1):

%1 вынесите из кавычек

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте не писать "@=". Пишите так:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\Shell\notepad\Command] 
"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Мои документы\Rnote_\Rnote.exe" "%1".

У меня работает.

Comment: Что-то сомнительно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить весь этот путь на "досовский" 
C:\Docume~1\....